# ListView creates one more item than needed

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` which is populated in my MainActivity, but when i want to find the selected item, all of the items appear to have the same position.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_teams);

        ListView mainListView;

        // Find the ListView in the UI.
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView );

        String values = "Team A vs Team B=Team C vs Team D";

        //Matches are send in one long string, and are separated by the = sign.
        //This splits the string up and puts it into an array.
        String[] array = values.split("=", -1);

        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        arraylist.addAll( Arrays.asList(array) );

        ArrayAdapter listAdapter;

        // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view_style, arraylist);


        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}
```

This makes a list like this:

```
Team A vs Team B    [checkbox]
Team C vs Team D    [checkbox]
```

I have a button and when it is clicked it runs this method:

```
public void matchStart(View view){

    String selectedMatch = String.valueOf(((ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView )).getSelectedItemPosition());

    Toast.makeText(SelectTeams.this, selectedMatch, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

However whenever i click the button, the toast displays the same value no matter which item in the listview is selected. Why is this?

Comment: You're getting the list position, for what you need, use getView method of your adapter

Answer (score 0):

You should use the adapters getView method, something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent,
                false);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           //here get what you need by the position

        }
    });
    }


 }
```

Comment: how would I implement this, Im relatively new to android.

Comment: It's not complicated, just extend ArrayAdapter, and do something like I answered. i will edit my answer, so it will be a bit more detailed.

Comment: Actually this will be much better then me trying to explain:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#arrayAdapter

Comment: but would this be able to retrieve the selected item when a button is pressed? instead of when the actual item is pressed?

Comment: Yes off-course. You'll be able to do anything you want with your ListView items.

Comment: Np, glad to help. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: thank you, it is an A2 computing project so its quite important!